# Creating a unique Id in rails while iterating over recurring dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iteration

I am using a method to create an array of dates, that is then iterated over to make a meeting, using this method:

```
[2021-03-21, 2021-03-22, 2021-03-23].map do |date|
   Meeting.new(id: id, user_id: user_id , name: name, start_time: date, 
   end_time: date, complete: complete, description: description)
 end
```

the meeting is then set using:

```
def set_meeting
  @meeting = Meeting.find(params[:id])
end
```

I have a boolean argument for meeting completed, so I need each Meeting to be created as a unique id, so I can view them as individual meetings on a calendar

Comment: Are `[2021-03-21, 2021-03-22, 2021-03-23]` really dates o_O ?? I don't know Rails but with Ruby these are numbers

Comment: You're right. I edited the values to make it easier to read quickly. I am using IceCube::Schedule from ice_cube gem. It produces an array as follows ```[2021-03-21 00:00:00 +0000, 2021-03-22 00:00:00 +0000, 2021-03-23 00:00:00 +0000]```

Comment: The comment from @Fravadona was based on the fact that in the post your `Array` is equivalent to `[1997,1996,1995]` because `-` is a mathematical operation being applied to the Integers. Instead you should change this to `['2021-03-21', '2021-03-22', '2021-03-23']` since rails will cast those `String`s to the correct data type for `start_time` and `end_time` (e.g. `Date`, `DateTime`)

Answer (score 1):

Here while initializing the meeting object no need to specify an id. Rails auto-generate sequential ids for your objects. After initializing the object you need to store/save this object in the Database. Using new you are only initializing objects on your memory but not storing them in the database. Once you store records in the database then it will be easy to get id from params and find a record in the database.

```
meeting = Meeting.new(user_id: user_id , name: name, start_time: date, 
   end_time: date, complete: complete, description: description)
meeting.save
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. When I don't assign an id, I get an ActionController error ```No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"meetings", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]```. I will dig through my code and see why this is happening

Comment: Yes. It is expected behavior in the rails framework. When you are calling show action, then you should provide id in params. Please refer  - https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html